# Save results from AWS Athena query in Zeppelin

Tags: jdbc, apache-zeppelin, amazon-athena

I'm able to successfully execute queries on Athena via my Zeppelin notebook, however I don't understand how to save the result set.

The following code displays a table

```
%athena
select * from table_name limit 5;
```

My goal is to save the results into a pandas dataframe, so I can do future transformations.

I'm able to save as CSV and import it manually, but this does not seem very efficient.

I'm using Zeppelin 0.8.0, and AthenaJDBC42-2.0.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to experiment with athena and execute with spark.
so basically:

```
%spark.pyspark
df = pd.read_sql("select * from table_name limit 5", conn)
```